# How to apply an atmospheric attenuation filter in the freq domain and then convert the filtered signal back to the time domain?

Tags: filtering, acoustics

This question is a part of a more general question the answer of which I don't know -
*How to apply a filter in the freq domain and then convert the filtered signal back to the time domain?* Well, I partially googled the answer that I need to

- convert the signal in FFT
- multiply by the filter
- convert back to the time domain

but I'm not entirely sure if I've applied this idea correctly to atmospheric absorption filtering (see below).

I'm also not sure whether I can do the filtering entirely in the time domain (as suggested [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19505/how-to-convert-filter-into-frequency-domain-to-do-filtering) by convolution?) somehow alleviating the need to switch back and forth to the freq domain.

Input: sound wave (gunshot sound pressure subtracted atmospheric pressure) and atmospheric conditions. Output: the same sound wave attenuated with an atmospheric absorption filter.

I'm using `python-acoustics` to find the atmospheric attenuation coefficient as described in [Engineering Acoustics/Outdoor Sound Propagation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Engineering_Acoustics/Outdoor_Sound_Propagation).

I've came up with the following code:

```
def atmosphericAttenuation(signal, distance, Fs, **kwargs):
    """
    Apply atmospheric absorption to the `signal` for all its FFT frequencies.
    It does not account for the geometrical attenuation.

    Parameters
    ----------
    signal - a pressure waveform (time domain)
    distance - the travelled distance, m
    Fs - sampling frequency of the `signal`, Hz
    kwargs - passed to `Atmosphere` class

    Returns
    -------
    signal_attenuated - attenuated signal in the original time domain
    """
    # pip install acoustics
    from acoustics.atmosphere import Atmosphere

    atm = Atmosphere(**kwargs)
    signal_rfft = np.fft.rfft(signal)
    freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(n=len(signal), d=1. / Fs)
    # compute the attenuation coefficient for each frequency
    a_coef = atm.attenuation_coefficient(freq)
    # (option 2) signal_rfft *= 10 ** (-a_coef * distance / 20)
    signal_rfft *= np.exp(-a_coef * distance)
    signal_attenuated = np.fft.irfft(signal_rfft)
    return signal_attenuated
```

Am I doing it right? Which one is correct:

- `signal_rfft *= np.exp(-a_coef * distance)` <- $P(r) = P(0) \exp (-\alpha r)$
- `signal_rfft *= 10 ** (-a_coef * distance / 20)` <- $A_a = -20 \log_{10} \frac{P(r)}{P(0)} = \alpha r$

If neither, please describe how it should be done.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FFT has a fixed frequency resolution and I don't recommend to do such a frequency modification with FFT. See more at this [question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-filter-by-zeroing-out-fft-bins).

You may use `Atmosphere.impulse_response` to obtain the impulse response and then apply a time-domain convolution, which gives a more reasonable result.

> Which one is correct:
>
> - `signal_rfft *= np.exp(-a_coef * distance)`
> - `signal_rfft *= 10 ** (-a_coef * distance / 20)`

According to the [documentation](http://python-acoustics.github.io/python-acoustics/atmosphere.html), attenuation coefficient $\alpha$ describing atmospheric absorption in dB/m as function of frequency. So the second one is correct.

Comment: Thank you! Do you mean `ir = atm.impulse_response(distance=distance, fs=Fs, ntaps=len(signal)); signal_attenuated = np.convolve(signal, ir, mode='same')`? Indeed, this looks better.

Comment: @dizcza yes that’s right